# about pointers in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

In the following questions, p1,p2, abd p3 are pointers to intergers. In the BEGINNING of each question *p1 and *p2 will both have the value 10.

after executing the following statements, what is the value of *p1 and *p2

```
p3 = NULL
p3 = p1
p1 = p2
p2 = p1
```

The way I did it i ended up getting 10 for both the same way they started.

```
p3 = NULL
p3 = p1 ;now p3 is set to 10
p1 = p2 ;now p1 is set to 10
p2 = p1 ;now p2 is set to 10
```

but I don't think I'm understanding it correctly.

Comment: You're right, they both end up pointing to a 10, but maybe to a different one than they started pointing to... seems like a weird question.

Comment: I thought It was weird just to go through all that to have them point to 10 again and the NULL really didn't really play a part in any of it.

Answer (score 0):

The last line sets p2 to p1, which was just set to p2; so both p1 and p2 point to the original target of p2, which contains the value 10.

Comment: So what if you where to set p3 = p1 then delete p1 does the value of p1 stay in p3 or is that also gone?

Comment: What do you mean by "delete p1"?

Comment: delete that memory location

Comment: @Zainee when you delete a pointer, the memory the pointer points to is being released to the operating system. If there is other pointer pointing to the same memory address, all bets are off if you're trying to de-reference the latter.

Comment: @vsoftco not trying change the latter just wondering what value p3 would hold after the value it point to (p1)  will be deleted. does that make sense?

Comment: `p3` will hold the same address, like `0xa05f782e`, however the address is not "yours" anymore. Trying to "see" (dereferencing) what's at that address via `*p3` leads to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse pointers to what they point to. `*p1` and `*p2` have value 10, that is, both `p1` and `p2` point to memory locations that have 10 written in it (although the memory locations may not be the same). It doesn't mean that `p1` and `p2` point to the same memory location!

Line by line:

```
p3 = p1; // p3 points to the memory location of p1, *p3 = *p1 = 10
p1 = p2; // p1 points to the memory location of p2, *p1 = *p2 = 10
p2 = p1; // p2 points to the memory location of p1, *p2 = *p1 = 10
```

So at the end of the day, you end up with: `p3` taking the value of the original `p1`, then `p1` taking the value of the original `p2`, and `p2` being left unchanged.

Comment: @Zainee try printing both the pointers and their values, like `cout << p << *p;` to convince yourself (I may be wrong, so it's better to double check)

Comment: Yes, Ill definitely print to check it once I finish all the questions thank you @vsoftco

Answer (score 0):

This is really like playing a shell game.

So lets start with that.. here is the state after each line:

> p1=orig1, p2=orig2, p3=orig3

p3 = NULL

> p1=orig1, p2=orig2, p3=NULL

p3 = p1 (currently set to orig1)

> p1=orig1, p2=orig2, p3=orig1

p1 = p2 (currently set to orig2)

> p1=orig2, p2=orig2, p3=orig1

p2 = p1 (currently set to orig2)

> p1=orig2, p2=orig2, p3=orig1

And as it said.. the original value of *p2 and *p1 is 10, so they will all be 10.

Comment: Oh so its setting to 10 but just at different memory locations then what is originally started at. Thank you

Comment: Um, no. Okay I need to explain pointers..

Think of pointers kind of like a notecard with the address to someone's house (the house in this case being the "10").

We aren't physically moving the house, we are just changing what is written on each notecard. So by doing p3 = p1 in the second line we are copying the address written on p1's notecard onto p3's notecard. Now both notecards have the address of p1's house on them.

Comment: oh okay. I get it. The whole address thing makes sense now.